# MvcRazorToPdf align content to bottom of page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, razor, pdf-generation, mvcrazortopdf

I am trying to get a footer in a generated pdf file. I am using this library
https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf

Is there any way to get some of my content to the bottom of the page? Unfortunately pdf does not respond to `position:absolute; bottom:0px;` or margin-bottom.

The page shows an unknown amount of records on the page, so I cannot do it statically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem. It's not very neat, but I doubt there are other ways since MvcRazorToPdf does not support the margin and position styles.

```
<table id="wrapper" style="height:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            Put your site content here.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="bottom">
            Put your footer here.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would recommend creating  a new table below the site content and then giving it valign="bottom"

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe but will the table resize to the rest of the content on the page?

Comment: Yeah it does i had implemented a complex structure containing 80 tables it worked properly i had to insert <br /> to pull it down a bit

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe thanks, that's a better solution than my current one then :)